# How unmarshal dynamic keys

Tags: go, yaml

I have a yaml file with the follow structure:

```
mappings:
  extgroup1:
  - somescope1
  - somescope2

  someextgroup:
  - somescope3

  allusers:
  - somescope1
```

The mappings are basically an array, but the structure is just a dynamic set of keys. I want to unmarshall this into an array of a new data type like so:

```
type ExternalGroupMapping struct {
    ExternalGroup string
    Scopes        []string
}
```

So, it would look something like:

```
[]Mappings{
     ExternalGroupMapping{
         ExternalGroup: "extgroup1"
         Scopes: []string{"somescope1", "somescope2"}
     },
     ExternalGroupMapping{
         ExternalGroup: "someextgroup"
         Scopes: []string{"somescope3"}
     },
     ExternalGroupMapping{
         ExternalGroup: "allusers"
         Scopes: []string{"somescope1"}
     }
}
```

Similar to something like `to_entries` in `jq`

Is something like this possible? Not even sure where to begin.

Thanks!

Comment: The struct schema needs to match the yml schema.  Based on your yaml that would be a `map[string][]string`  if you want to turn that into `[]struct{string,[] string` without changing your yaml schema, do it after parsing the yaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without custom marshaling, you can do this by mapping dynamic keys to map keys. Each mapping appear to be an array of scopes, so:

```
type Mappings struct {
   Mappings map[string][]string `yaml:"mappings"`
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what i figured. This makes sense. I'll try it this way and see if this will work for me. If not, ill adjust.